# Error in compressing the citation in Tufte-book

Tags: natbib, tufte, multiple-citations, tufte-book

I'm using Tufte book class to write my thesis. I'm having a bit of a problem in putting up the references. First of all, I want the citations to look like `[1-4]` rather than `[1,2,3,4]`. I'm using

```
\setcitestyle{square,numbers,sort&compress}
```

and also

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{sample-handout}
```

But I'm still getting citations with format `[1;2;3;4]`. Furthermore, it appears that it's not reorganizing the option `sort&compress` since it's showing it in red. Note that I'm using `\citep{}` when citing a reference.

---

I'm also getting errors such as

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode character (U+2009)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. C.~Monroe, W.

even when I put

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Ensure UTF-8 encoding is used
```

and

> Missing $ inserted. ...block \doi{10.1364/CLEO_QELS.2016.FTh4C.1}

The citation looks like

```
@article{White:16,
author = {Andrew G. White},
booktitle = {Conference on Lasers and Electro-Optics},
journal = {Conference on Lasers and Electro-Optics},
keywords = {Biology; Chemistry; Detectors},
pages = {FTh4C.1},
publisher = {Optica Publishing Group},
title = {Photonic Quantum Simulation},
year = {2016},
url = {https://opg.optica.org/abstract.cfm?URI=CLEO_QELS-2016-FTh4C.1},
doi = {10.1364/CLEO_QELS.2016.FTh4C.1},
abstract = {We review photonic quantum simulation, its use in biology, chemistry, computer science and physics, and its prospects for scaling given the latest advances in quantum photonics, notably in sources, detectors, and nonlinear interactions.},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does your code load the `xurl` package? And, what happens if you use `\cite` instead of `\citep`?

Comment: My code doesn't load xurl package. When I use \cite, it starts to give citations on the margin. I don't want that since it's become messy with lots of citations at hand.

Answer (score 1):

While I couldn't immediately confirm from the source of `tufte-book`, I suspect that the redefinitions of cite commands prevent `sort&compress` from taking effect. However, if you set this option when `natbib` is loaded, in this case using `\PassOptionsToPackage` before loading the class, then the sort & compress behavior is preserved.

The `Missing $ inserted` is caused by an unescaped `_` character in the `doi` field. The `url` field also has this character, but that field is parsed verbatim while `doi` is parsed as normal text, so `_` is seen as a subscript for which math mode (i.e., `$`) is required. The fix for this is therefore

```
doi = {10.1364/CLEO\_QELS.2016.FTh4C.1},
```

Full code:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{White:16,
author = {Andrew G. White},
booktitle = {Conference on Lasers and Electro-Optics},
journal = {Conference on Lasers and Electro-Optics},
keywords = {Biology; Chemistry; Detectors},
pages = {FTh4C.1},
publisher = {Optica Publishing Group},
title = {Photonic Quantum Simulation},
year = {2016},
url = {https://opg.optica.org/abstract.cfm?URI=CLEO_QELS-2016-FTh4C.1},
doi = {10.1364/CLEO\_QELS.2016.FTh4C.1},
abstract = {We review photonic quantum simulation, its use in biology, chemistry, computer science and physics, and its prospects for scaling given the latest advances in quantum photonics, notably in sources, detectors, and nonlinear interactions.},
}
@misc{White:17,
author = {John White},
title = {Number 17},
year = {2017}
}
@misc{White:18,
author = {Mary White},
title = {Number 18},
year = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents}
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers,sort&compress}{natbib}
\documentclass{tufte-book}
%\setcitestyle{square,numbers,sort&compress}
\title{Sort \& Compress}
\author{with Tufte Book}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Some cite commands}
\citep{White:16,White:17,White:18}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

For the utf8 characters you don't give the source of the offending bib entry. However, the error in general is well-known and refers to the fact that pdfLaTeX can only handle a limited amount of utf8 characters natively (basically extended ascii, so latin letters with diacritics), and if you have other utf8 characters then you need to set them up individually using `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` (or use a package that sets things up, for example for CJK).

For this specific character U+2009 this is not needed however, that is a 'thin space' which probably was inserted into the entry by mistake. You can try to find the character using visual inspection or a hex editor for example, or just retype the entry (so don't copy and paste, actually retype from scratch).